# SportsfeedAPI Not Displaying Info (Ruby Wesbite)

Tags: html, ruby, api, view, controller

I am trying to create a simple Ruby website that will display NFL scores using the SportsfeedAPI from Rapid API's. Currently, it is not displaying the scores. I have tried to link the controller and view together, but it is not displaying on my ruby website. I am unsure where in my code I went wrong.

Here is my controller view:

```
require 'excon'
require 'sinatra'

class LiveScoresController < ApplicationController

  def fetch_games()
    url = "https://sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com/games?league=NFL"

    response = Excon.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host' => 'XXX',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key' => 'sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    )
    JSON.parse(response.body)['results']
  end

def game
get '/' do
  @games = fetch_games()
  erb :scores, locals: { games: games }
end
end
end
```

And here is my scores view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container2">
      <section>
        <h1 class="text-center">Scores</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



<% if @games.try(:any?) %>
  <section>
    <% @games.each do |games| %>
      <div class="scoreboard">
            <!-- Home Team Name and Score -->
            <div class="scoreboard__name">
              <h4><%= games['scoreboard']['score']['home'] %></h4>
              <p><%= games['teams']['home']['team'] %></p>
            </div>
            <!-- Dash separator -->
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <h4>&mdash;</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Away Team Name and Score -->
            <div class="scoreboard__name">
              <h4><%= games['scoreboard']['score']['away'] %></h4>
              <p><%= games['teams']['away']['team'] %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the return value of the `fetch_games` method to the `@games` instance variable but then pass `games` to the view.

Just change that to:

```
get '/' do
  @games = fetch_games
  erb :scores, locals: { games: @games }
end
```

Comment: OP: Futhermore this is masked by your use of `try` in the view `if @games.try(:any?)`. This becomes `nil.try(:any?) #=> nil`. I have never really found `try` to be all that useful because there is too much magic and it can have the impact of hiding otherwise obvious bugs (which you are now experiencing)